# Buttons are not working in Fragment activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, tabs

The buttons in my fragment are unresponsive.

I basically tried to implement https://demonuts.com/pick-image-gallery-camera-android/ inside a fragment of my app. It is working under a normal project when I use AppCompatActivity.

```
public class PeopleTab extends Fragment {

    Button btn;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/demonuts";
    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.people_layout, container, false);

        requestMultiplePermissions();

        btn = (Button) view3.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        imageview = (ImageView) view3.findViewById(R.id.iv);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPictureDialog();
            }
        });
        return view3;
    }
```

I want the button to work, but nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: clear cache and restart then it should work

Comment: clean project and rebuild... It will work.. and put  requestMultiplePermissions(); inside the button click listener...

Comment: None of those worked

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .xml(layout) file button should not overlapped by other view.

Comment: It is not overlapped by another view but my button is not in people_layout, does that matter anyhow?